# Convert a 3D Tensor back into an image (jpg/png)

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I want to use the [Tensorflow Camera](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/0.2.1/#cameraWithTensors) component which returns a Tensor3D for each frame of the camera preview. This is great for live classification with tensorflow models, however, I want to be able to convert this tensor back into a jpg or image format to be used with an OCR library like Tesseract.

Is there any way to convert a <tf.Tensor3d> into a more traditional image format for general use ?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [tf.node.encodeJpeg](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_node/1.3.0/#node.encodeJpeg) or [tf.node.encodePng](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_node/1.3.0/#node.encodePng) but they require that the 3D Tensor passed in is of type `uint8`.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the returned int32 from the imageTensor to a uint8?

Comment: Thanks for these, I saw but unfortunately my Tensor is in int32, i've made a feature request on the tensorflow page so hopefully they can expand the available inputs

Comment: I was thinking `tf.cast` would work but then it only supports casting to `int32`.

Comment: That was not the question in the first place, he is using React Native, `encodePng` and `encodeJpeg` are not available.